# libprotobuf fatal google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:78 This program was compiled against version 2.6.1

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I'm installing Opencv on Ubuntu with VMWARE following [this website](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/).

I finished installing opencv and at Step #6, I put import cv2 and got this error:

```
[libprotobuf fatal /home/psh/opencv-master/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google
/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:78] This program was compiled against version
2.6.1 of the protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible
with the installed version(3.1.0)...
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly What is the reason. But I got the same problem like you. But instead of fix this error. I try new way to install OpenCV.
And I follow steps in this website: http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

Run these commands

`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
sudo apt-get autoremove libopencv-dev python-opencv`

Download [this script](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh) and Run

`source install-opencv.sh`

After about 1-hour installation, we can test by:

`python
import cv2
cv2.__version__`

If you want to install OpenCV in your virtualenv too, follow step #5 at [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) (your tutorial)